# Where do I put my web services?

Tags: filesystems, users, services

I'm administrating my server since a few year but I'm looking for good practice like:

- What is the best place web service like my wordpress website files? My [etherpad-lite](http://etherpad.org/) instance?
- Which user shall own these files?
- Which user shall run these services?

I'm concerned about security but want to keep it simple at the beginning. Thank you in advance for your information!